# Group data from 2 table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry, guys.I am quite new in mysql but I do need help from getting and merging data from 2 tables.

```
table_a

ID | TITLE | CONTENT | DATE

table_b

ID | POST_ID | IMAGE
```

Here's my code

```
$query = "SELECT table_a.*, table_b.IMAGE FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
      ON table_a.ID = table_b.POST_ID
      ORDER BY table_a.DATE";
$mysql_result = mysql_query($query);

$result = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)) {
   $result[] = $row;
}
print json_encode($result);
```

However, for those record in table_a which got more than 1 IMAGE, my json contain duplicated CONTENT with different IMAGES.

Is there any methods to *merge IMAGE with the same ID* into a single record?

Thanks for any helps!

Comment: What do you mean by "merge image with the same ID into a single record"?  I suspect that you have multiple images with different IDs but for the same POST_ID - hence you're getting multiple records back.  What behaviour do you want to achive?  What results do you need to get if you have multiple images for the same post?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aleks. The result I need is something like
[{"ID":"1","TITLE":"Hello World","DATE":"2011-08-10","CONTENT":"I am newbie.", "IMAGE":"a.jpg,b.jpg,c.jpg"},{"ID":"2"...}. So I can display thumbnails and title / content by parsing in jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have all fields from table_a, and only one (maybe combined) field from table_b.

First of all, you have to decide what you want to get, if you have more than one image:

- Only 1 image? Use `MIN(table_b.IMAGE)` or `MAX(table_b.IMAGE)` in the
  following SQL
- All images separated by e.g. a comma? Use `GROUP_CONCAT(table_b.IMAGE SEPARATOR ',')` or similar in the following SQL

Next you have to understand, that to get only one row per `table_a.ID`, you have to group by `table_a.ID`, so we have

```
SELECT
  table_a.*,
  <function from above> AS image
FROM  table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
      ON table_a.ID = table_b.POST_ID
GROUP BY table_a.ID
ORDER BY table_a.DATE
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. BTW I got this error now :Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .... in line52

Comment: What have you chosen? Pleast post complete SQL

Comment: Please mind, there was a typo in my answer: There was `SEAPRATOR` (wrong) which I now corrected to `SEPARATOR`

Comment: Thank very much. It works perfectly now! I should post my question here early so I should have save many hrs. Thank you again :) Sorry that this is my first post, so I don't have enough reputation to vote this up.

Comment: If it worked for you, you can accept the answer, by clicking the check mark beside it. Accepting answers to your questions motivates others on SO to look at your next questions.

Comment: Got it :) Cheers and have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You can use the GROUP_CONCAT function to group the images as a comma-delimited list in one column of your posts table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is something like this:

```
SELECT table_a.*, GROUP_CONCAT(table_b.IMAGE) FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.ID = table_b.POST_ID
GROUP BY table_a.*
ORDER BY table_a.DATE
```

(Not sure if you have to spell out the `GROUP BY` clause, listing field names individually, or whether `.*` notation will be accepted here.)

Answer (score -1):

You can perhaps use **JOIN** instead of **LEFT JOIN** . In this way it will only load one row

or the other way

put `GROUP BY a.ID` jsut before ORDER BY...